# How to put a label in the center of a UMAP scatter series when using echarts for ploting?

Tags: javascript, plot, echarts

I want to plot a cluster scatter using echarts, the current plot i draw is like this:
[image]

Each series respresent a cluset, and now i want to put the legend label of each series in its own center, some my current code  snippet is like this:

```
var series = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cell_type.length; i++) {
    series.push({
      name: cell_type[i],
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: "top",
        color: "#000",
        fontSize: 10,
        formatter: function (params) {
          if (params.dataIndex === 0) {
            // show labels only at points with data index 0
            return params.data[2];
          } else {
            return "";
          }
        },
      },
      type: "scatter",
      emphasis: {
        focus: "series",
      },
      datasetIndex: i + 1,
      symbolSize: 2,
      encode: {
        x: "x",
        y: "y",
      },
    });
  }
```

And my dataset of each series is like this:

['-4.03', '-1.99', '1.Normal.Gpr182.Stab2']

['0.31', '5.25', '5.Irf1.Cxcl10']

['9.24', '-6.13', '8.Cycling.Mki67']

Currently i just put the label in the first index. So how can I modify the formatter function above so that i can put the label in the center of each series？

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Sort your dataset such that the first point is one close to the center.

Option 2: Precompute your center and use the [label position](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.label.position) to set the exact position that you want. The position is in pixels so you will have to consider how much space is occupied by the axes, etc.

Here is an example to play around with: [Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=PTAEHMFMDtIJwIYBdKgCbIQKAGYFdoBjJASwHtpRC5JlIBhAGzwGcU4AKQmdgGlERoSrABr9BwlgE1-0OAAUyJaEhYBKUAG8soKhTZVmbeKAC8oANoBdANw7QOMnFAdGkJKBJnQABhufQAB5QOUVlVX8SAGoojW1dXUJ9DwAPb24VeAA6NKiBaDQOAFoJUXEEIVE1OwS9aAMAT3SebKa8uALi0ulyyulq-0SjdiyAB1YACw5NUBSALln-BoWG_gz2BfX4AF8B3W37GiQ8DsNWdjsD_CJSCnzCgFtlfgeEFLjD9xPKAFlkCayiAKZAeHA0ACoXK80kVQE9oBo8vDLlgsEl6h4MEgECx3AAZEgGcwWezxBIkNALADkAEYqbxBqAWGQTtxNjQ6ExzvBprMFgAOADsSwWNIAzKBtvxxdKAEz8fk0tT2KWkxkU6my-mM5msyDs2goLnGTgzeagMUAFhFoEFNMl0v5Cv4goAnMr9gzdGTdBrQFSxdrarq4GyqByjcMeWbRcLQMtQLKJVLQABWF38WWCj0OtW1P1Uy1BhIhsPUQ0MKOmvm21021M-B0W9OJnzShs5g62VEgUCQQgTBBwDzonAkcAnZDkaBYNweXFwEiQFgEomWbuOZyudzoTCgMg4XfY3FIVdID66BdLleEpBjSbTRlIBqjfX-liEZDsYu6LE49wAJKUkeCBZBSXoJNACAPG-VJ_ie_qgHkf5gWgEG6IwCAAEaQIwCw-iWExkAA7gsSBwHgkDoQkoxkCwJC3NACwWChpaQBYPhWBYVJbHAVJcVSKT8fwrEsqG7GcdxvH8dxDT8VY1G6JurxIBsDgEMQ04uKMQ7QeoWiMrUvqHhwOmIA8LBZH-AEFJAaSmA5vgXkZLm9iwRHEaAmE4YwLD7tAjBNMgoC0eEfnEQxEwgZ4tlpD4hkuQIXynGZelWZgHHdolCTbH2vmoAR2VHN8oAAESlTU2WSglnqMgc-wDAcWBkKMjHeGS8HuAsnWnreEFuFABT4aqugINAJAqdOCw4Ag-UQSkACCKSEsNEENEtK1aCNTLwNeCxXsuZ5YNsNhAA)